# How to extend a Ruby library with a helper object

Tags: ruby

I'm extending [Prawn-Rails](https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails) with [PrawnRailsForms](https://github.com/umts/prawn-rails-forms). I want those methods to only be available within a block that gives them some context. For example, usage of my extension might look like:

```
field_row height: 25, units: 8 do
  text_field field: 'Favorite fruit', # ...
end
```

The way this works under the hood in my library is that the `field_row` method instantiates a helper object, without which the other methods, like  `text_field`, don't run:

```
class FieldRow
  # ...
end

class PrawnRails::Document

  attr_accessor :field_row # my helper object

  def field_row(height:, units:, &block)
     @field_row = FieldRow.new #...
     block.call
     @field_row = nil
  end

  def text_field(**args)
    unless @field_row.present?
      raise ArgumentError, 'Must be inside a field row'
    end
    # implementation which relies on @field_row...
  end
end
```

Is there a nicer way to make sure that my methods are only run when the `FieldRow` object is available? In particular, having to write `@field_row = nil` after `block.call` makes me feel like I'm doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a nicer way to make sure that my methods are only run in the proper context, e.g. when the `FieldRow` object is available?

APIs like this usually use [`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) so that the methods inside the block are called on the instantiated object:

```
module PrawnRailsForms
  class FieldRow
    def initialize(height:, units:, **)
      # ...
    end

    def text_field(field:, **)
      # ...
    end
  end

  module Document
    def field_row(**args, &block)
      @field_row = FieldRow.new(**args)
      @field_row.instance_eval(&block) unless block.nil?
      @field_row
    end
  end

  ::PrawnRails::Document.include(Document)
end
```

Now when you do this:

```
doc.field_row(height: 25, units: 8) do
  text_field field: 'Favorite fruit'
end
```

...it will instantiate a FieldRow object with `height:` and `units:`, then call `text_field` on that object.

---

If you need FieldRow to operate on the document itself, there are a few approaches you could take. One is to just pass `self` (the document object) to FieldRow's constructor and store it in an instance variable therein for use by `text_field` et al:

```
def field_row(**args, &block)
  row = FieldRow.new(self, **args)
  row.instance_eval(&block) unless block.nil?
end
```

You could also define a method on FieldRow to which you pass the document object. In this scenario, FieldRow's methods (e.g. `text_field`) "configure" the output and `render` (or whatever you choose to call it) actually creates the output.

```
def field_row(**args, &block)
  row = FieldRow.new(**args)
  row.instance_eval(&block) unless block.nil?
  row.render(self)
end
```

I would caution against adding a bunch of methods to Document. Since `text_field` only works inside the context of `field_row`, making `text_field` an instance method on Document doesn't really make sense (and, as you've discovered, has some gotchas).

Comment: Hmm, except `text_field` needs to be an instance method of `PrawnRails::Document`, so that it can operate on the document (creating boxes, adding text, styling, etc.).

Comment: @dfaulken You may wish to explore how Prawn itself implements similar methods, since it may have an established convention (or even some convenient functionality you can piggyback onto), but I've edited my answer to include a couple possible solutions.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. Thank you for sharing so many ideas!